# Creating a "triangle border" around a circle with Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, borders

I'm trying to create a shape that looks like this:

[image]

Where there's a circle with a border that is of a particular shape, in this case a triangle. I know that you can add borders to shapes as well as "fake" borders with shadows with no elevation. But I'm not sure how to make a border with some arbitrary shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sketch, the process is a little different than what you're used to in Illustrator or Inkscape. Since there's no concept of brushes, you need to make the shape you'd like to duplicate in the circle and then choose "Layer" > "Paths" > "Rotate Copies". Sketch will ask you for a number of copies and will let you place the center over which to rotate.

It's not as elegant as brushes, but it should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Any closed path (shape) has a border and the border can be treated as a shape also. If you join a circle and a square they will now have an irregular border which you can edit or make invisible.

I'm sensing the questions "How do I make this saw blade shape?" and "how do I make a border that has a saw tooth pattern and apply it to various shapes?"

There are several options to draw the saw blade. I made a 64 point star and twisted it.

To make a saw tooth border pattern you can draw a few sample saw teeth then make a brush of them and apply it to a circle:
[image]

With the pen tool draw a sawtooth. Make sure its a closed (completed) path. Copy it and paste twice to make 3 teeth.

Make a rectangle that's wide and flat. Place the teeth on the rectangle, align bottom everything and then align the three teeth equidistant horizontally "Horizontal Distribute Center". Select the three teeth and the rectangle and use pathfinder "combine".

Make your shape small then drag it into the brushes pallet and select  "Pattern Brush". Then apply the brush to the stroke of a circle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I only have access to sketch at the moment so I'm not sure where to find AI's brush tool analog in Sketch 3

Comment: You can do something similar in Inkscape which is free, using pattern along a path.  http://imgur.com/Sgw88DB